# Not repeating random page background by storing in browser

Tags: jquery, random, background-image, browser-cache, repeat

So I am very much a beginner at JS and I wrote a really simple script for randomly selecting a background image for pages on my site.  The problem is sometimes when navigating to a new page or reloading the same page the same image will be randomly selected.  I need some way of storing which image has just been used as the background in the browser.

Here is my script:

```
    var rand_image_bg = function(){
        $('<div id="background_container"><img class="background_image"/></div>').insertAfter("#menu");
        var image_src = ["Images/spaceship.jpg", "Images/hallway.jpg", "Images/steampunk.jpg", "Images/mine.jpg"];
        var selected_bg_image = Math.floor((Math.random()*image_src.length)+1)-1;
        console.log($("body").data("bg_image"));
        if (selected_bg_image == /*Number of the previous background image*/) {
            selected_bg_image = image_src.length-1-selected_bg_image;
        }
        $(".background_image").attr("src",""+image_src[selected_bg_image]+"");
        /*Record number of the new background image for later*/
    }
```

Any advice anyone can give me would be great.  Please keep in mind that I am a beginner so keep it simple.  THANKS!

Comment: There are generally only three ways to keep state in HTML (there are many more, but these three are most commonly used). Using cookies or localStorage to store the information on the clientside, or store the information on the serverside. The first two are probably most relevant for this.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery already, look into jquery.cookie.js plugin... It's pretty easy to store and pull cookies with it.  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie  Just simpley store the index of the path you used for your image_src array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following adeno's advice I wrote this and it seems to work:

```
    var rand_image_bg = function(){
        $('<div id="background_container"><img class="background_image"/></div>').insertAfter("#menu");
        var image_src = ["Images/spaceship.jpg", "Images/hallway.jpg", "Images/steampunk.jpg", "Images/mine.jpg"];
        var selected_bg_image = Math.floor((Math.random()*image_src.length)+1)-1;
        if (selected_bg_image == localStorage.bg_image) {
            selected_bg_image = image_src.length-1-selected_bg_image;
        }
        $(".background_image").attr("src",""+image_src[selected_bg_image]+"");
        localStorage.bg_image = selected_bg_image;
    }
    rand_image_bg();
```